# Как сделать приватный репозиторий на Github публичным?

Tags: github

Я делал так - Settings=>Options=> поставил радиобаттон на make public, но нигде не вижу кнопку подтверждения confirm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала вам необходимо зайти в ваш репозиторий на гитхабе и перейти в настройки
[image: пример репозитория на гитхабе]

После этого необходимо прокрутить низ до раздела "Danger Zone". В самом разделе есть "Change repository visibility", необходимо нажать Change visibility.[image: раздел Danger Zone]

Выбираем "Make public", вводим имя своего репозитория и потверждаем изменения[image: настройка доступа к репозиторию].

Comment: Спасибо, добрый человек

Comment: @user455677 если не трудно повысите мой ответ) (кнопочка верх рядом с отвтеом)